# How to find out (or what is) the correct Docker Host Url to use in jenkins to specify Docker host?

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins, server, containers

I have docker (docker for windows server) and jenkins both running on a windows server 2019 and I am trying to add Docker Host URI in Jenkins but I ran into timeout error or connection refused error all time and cannot connect to docker host.

I tried the following urls:
tcp://:2375 (or 2376),
tcp://localhost:2375 (or 2376),
tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 (or 2376)

Do I have to configure anything else on docker or jenkins?. I cannot move forward in this issue. it would really help me if any one can provide some guidance to solve this.

Comment: Did you set the proper Docker daemon flags, so Docker is actually listening on the TCP port? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am facing the same problem now

Comment: @MrfksIV no I haven't find a solution to this yet

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar issue. You need to expose your docker demon at port 2375. I did it via docker desktop.

Then added HOST URl as  **tcp://127.0.0.1:2375**

[image]